# ¿Por qué sucede este error en VB.NET? System.InvalidCastException: 'Conversion from string "" to type 'Integer' is not valid.'

Tags: vb.net

soy un poco nuevo en en lenguaje VB.NET, tengo un pequeño problema con un fragmento de mi código, espero puedan ayudarme, muchas gracias!

Estoy intentando hacer que un archivo .csv que ya está agregado en un control TreeView se abra en un control DataGridView haciendo doble click sobre él. Sin embargo, al intentar correr el programa me muestra el error que agregué en el título. Sucede en la variable "Dirreción".

```
Public Sub TV_NodeMouseDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs) Handles TV.NodeMouseDoubleClick


Dim NombreNodo As String = TV.SelectedNode.Text

Dim parseCSV As String

Dim tstSeq() As String

Dim Direccion As String = My.Computer.FileSystem.CurrentDirectory(NombreNodo)

'Dim x As String = Path.GetFullPath(NombreNodo)

'MessageBox.Show(Direccion)

tstSeqDataGrid.Rows.Clear()

Using FileSystem As FileStream = File.Open(Direccion, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
    Dim TestReader As New System.IO.StreamReader(FileSystem)

    Do While TestReader.Peek <> -1
        parseCSV = TestReader.ReadLine()
        tstSeq = parseCSV.Split(",")
        tstSeqDataGrid.Rows.Add(tstSeq)
        TstSequenceLoaded = True
    Loop

    TestReader.Close()
    FileSystem.Close()

End Using

End Sub
```

Comment: El problema puede ser que en tu grid tienes alguna columna como que es numero, y en tu csv, lees un string y lo spliteas por ",", por lo que sigue siendo un string al final,  cambia tu grid para que todo lo maneje como string, o tendrás que generar ya sea un objeto y parsear tu variable `tstSeq`  a ese objeto o un datarow y ahi parsear antes de insertar los datos al datarow.

Comment: @EduardoJaramilloLicea Gracias por la respuesta. En verdad lo solucioné utilizando la línea de código que comenté:  `Dim x As String = Path.GetFullPath(NombreNodo)`. Pero ahora lo que hace es buscar en la carpeta en donde está guardado en código del programa, en este caso  entra a la carpeta Debug para buscar el archivo, únicamente faltaría definir bien el lugar exacto que debe buscar.